# How to access github account after deleting the ssh key

Tags: git, github

After deleting the ssh keys from my github account it gives permission denied error.

How to access my github account without recreating the ssh keys.

Comment: It may not help, but I would create another and add that to my github account. Then delete the old key.

Answer (score 1):

You still can access it through https, using your GitHub account credentials.

That would be your GitHub user account as a login, and your GitHub password.
You can also create a [PAT (Personnal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/), easier to manage than an SSH key, and easier to revoke if need be.

If you don't use 2FA (two factor authentication), such [credentials can be cached](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/) (except on Windows, it is no longer wincred, like the GitHub documentation incorrectly mention, but "manager": `git config --global credential.helper manager`)

Comment: I switch to use HTTP and cloned the project, its worked to me, thanks